# How to get p tags to go from a stacked position to left to right in a responsive email

Tags: html, css, responsive-emails

I've been creating a responsive email and I've been having some issues with the Desktop/Mobile changes. I want the Desktop version to look something like this:

```
Order Summary                Shipping Address
12345                         111 Broadway st
```

And the Mobile to look like this:

```
Order Summary     12345
Shipping Address   111 Broadway Street
```

I've tried a few ways already and while it works in the html inspection on my local server, it doesn't work when I send the test email to a client server.

The snippet of code shows the base email template of one of the div sections there, any insight would be much appreciated

```
     @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

      .two-column {
        max-width: 50%!important;
        width: 50% !important;
        background-color: #730E15!important;
      }

    }

<td class="two-column" style="padding: 5px 0 10px 0;text-align: center;font-size: 0;">
    <div class="section" style="width: 50%;max-width: 300px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;">
            <table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: sans-serif;color: #727f80;">
              <tr>
                <td class="inner-td" style="padding: 10px;">
                  <table class="content" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: sans-serif;color: #727f80;width: 50%;padding-top: 20px;font-size: 16px;line-height: 20px;text-align: justify;">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding: 0;">
                        <p>Order Number</p>
                        <p> 12345 </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div> <!--- End First Column of Two Columns -->
```

Comment: Have you tried making _two_ sets of headers on the same page - one horizontal and one vertical? That way, you can use CSS to show/hide the desired header  based on the screen width

Comment: @Code Slinger    So have both header versions typed out, but have one header hiding based on the screen size?

Comment: Tried to add the CSS inside a <style> tag?

Comment: the media query is in a <style>tag I just forgot to make sure it was showing here. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

You can have both horizontal vertical headers in your HTML, and then show the right header based on screen size.

You can use CSS [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width) to show the desired header based on screen width.

As an alternative, if you use `<div>`s instead of `<table>`s, you can use media queries to have the "columns" float horizontally on desktop but stack vertically on mobile.